# Configure StructureMap to find implementations for proxy classes

Tags: c#, structuremap, episerver, castle-dynamicproxy

I wonder if it's possible to configure StructureMap to handle proxy class instances as the underlying instance.

My problem is that the CMS I'm using (called Episerver) creates proxy instances of the classes I define, for example `MyBlock` will be instantiated as a proxy with the type `MyBlockProxy`. So even though I configure StructureMap to resolve `IMyInterface<MyBlock>` it fails when I try to resolve an instance of `IMyInterface<MyBlockProxy>`.

Episerver uses **Castle DynamicProxy** to generate the proxied instances.

Is it possible to configure StructureMap so that it resolves `IMyInterface<MyBlockProxy>` in the same way as `IMyInterface<MyBlock>`?

Comment: Cannot remember exactly but I recall us using `TypeInterceptor` combined with `ProxyGenerator()`, this was, however, a while ago. Now to a more general recommendation - don't put any Page/Blocktypes/Epi contentdata in the container until we get the new framework where replacing StructureMap will (most likely) be possible. Instead, allow epi to resolve its stuff and put your implementation in View and ContentModels where you are in control.

Comment: Could you describe the scenario, i.e. what you need to accomplish? I haven't come across this as being a problem, so it's probably a pattern I haven't come across. But in general I agree with @EricHerlitz above. :)